# ScrollTo can't read propperty top

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm trying to have my page slide to the next bit of content on a click, but I ran into a small problem.

```
$("#projects").click(function (e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var  container = $('#container-content'),
      scrollTo = $('#content-projects');

  container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
  }, 1500, 'easeInSine', function () {});
});
```

When I click on `projects` I get this back, `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` When I link to the the div before #content-projects (#content-me) the code does work.

http://codepen.io/alucardu/pen/lrgJo

Comment: off topic: if you use this `.click(function(e){`, you should really use `e.preventDefault();` instead of `event.peventDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small typo on my html. Found the problem and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
scrollTop: $(scrollTo).offset().top - $(container).offset().top + container.scrollTop()
```

You can't use just the variable of an element in combination with jQuery, you always have to put it in the jQuery `$()` wrapper.

For `container.scrollTop()` I think it should work because `scrollTop()` is native JS, although maybe it doesn't because you saved the element into the container-var using jQuery in the first place

Comment: Huh, so `scrollTo.offset().top` works fine? I could have sworn it wouldn't:D alright, learned something new

Comment: Yea, it was getting weird because in another project it worked fine. Ugh. Typo's are the bane of my existence.

Comment: Ctrl-C -> Ctrl-V, also known as copypaste:)